# Resistors for 3W RGB LED

Tags: led, current, resistors

I have 3.3V switching power supply. I want to power 3W RGB LED.

Forward voltages are: 2.2~2.8V(Red), 3.0~3.8V(Green), 3.0~3.8V(Blue)
Current: ~350mA

Should I use current limiting resistors? As I understand, for Red I need to drop 3.3V to under 2.8V and the resistor is necessary, but how to be with Green and Blue? Can I connect them directly?

Please explain.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the LED?

Comment: You should always use some form of current limiting, whether a constant current source or resistor.

Comment: Green and blue cannot be lit. Possible if Vf is exactly 3.3 or lesser but you never know. The variation of forward voltage and current is too high. You may have to pump up the voltage using boost regulators and then have constant current circuit or simple resistors limiting current.

Comment: @CHendrix These are cheap chinese LEDs, something like https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10pcs-High-Power-3W-RGB-LED-Chip-COB-SMD-LED-Beads-Red-Green-Blue-for-DIY/32755116945.html

Comment: @Colin__s can you explain a little bit why?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#/media/File:Diode-IV-Curve.svg once your powersupply voltage is greater than the LED's forward voltage current rises very quickly. Matching your power supply exactly to the LED's Vf is a dodgy game as the Vf will change with temperature.

Comment: Look any LED's datasheet. Find the graph of applied oltage vs current. It's exponential soon after the Vf mark. If you want to glow the LED, get a constant current circuit rigged up and Wish the selected LEDa have Vf of less than 3.3 V.

Comment: And if the Vf is 3.5V and my PS is 3.3V, how can I exceed the Vf?

Comment: It won't lit. You can only use those LEDs from the batch whose Vf is less than supply. Why not go for boost regulators?

Comment: Ok, which is the Vf in my case, because they specify different values, like 3.2-3.6V?

Comment: It might be anywhere in that range.

Comment: So I need to raise voltage slowly until I will get 350mA?

Comment: can you change the LEDs? can you use one boost regulator? if not, no other way, some of the green LEDs may lit some green LEDs may not. place a 1 ohm resistor in series for blue and green LEDs and 4 ohms for red LEDs. atleast, some of the green and blue LEDs may glow. can you also check, whether you can change your output of switching regulator to 5 v or anything higher than 4 V?

Comment: @RomanSimonyan You have to limit and balance the current somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get there from here.

3.3V is not enough the reliably light the green and blue parts.
and the red part with only between 0.5 and 1.1V spare may give variable performance if you use a 3.1 ohm resistor.

look instead for switched-mode LED driver that's compatible with your supply and LED.

Answer (score -2):

I think it won't be a problem, for diodes have a particular current value for each voltage, thus for 350mA rated current, rated voltage would be the point on its V-T characteristics plot.

Comment: There will be a problem, once the diode exceeds it's drop voltage it ligths up proportional to the intensity of the current, if no resistor is used then the current will be limited by the power supply's internal resistance implying any small peak of voltage will turn into a huge amount of increase of current burning the LED.